# Resolving dependency issues with Microsoft.AspNet packages when migrating from .NET Framework to .NET 6

Tags: dependencies, nuget, migration, .net-6.0, .net-4.8

I'm currently migrating a project from .NET Framework to .NET 6, and I'm encountering issues with the `Microsoft.AspNet` dependencies.

Specifically, I have the following packages in my project file:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.Cors" Version="5.2.7" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR" Version="2.2.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core" Version="2.2.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.JS" Version="2.2.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SystemWeb" Version="2.2.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" Version="5.2.5" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" Version="5.2.7" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" Version="5.2.7" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors" Version="5.2.7" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" Version="5.2.5" />
```

However, when trying to migrate these packages to their .NET 6 equivalents from `Microsoft.AspNetCore`, I noticed that most of them are marked as deprecated.

I understand that `Microsoft.AspNetCore` provides similar functionality, but I'm unsure about the best approach to address these dependency issues. I don't want to rely on deprecated packages, but I still need to ensure the smooth migration of my project.

Has anyone encountered a similar situation when migrating from .NET Framework to .NET 6 and dealing with `Microsoft.AspNet` packages? What alternatives or best practices can you recommend for resolving these dependency conflicts and maintaining compatibility with the new framework?

Thank you for any guidance or suggestions you can provide.

Comment: You should remove them and use the ones which come with the (ASP) .NET Core SDK/runtime and adjust code accordingly. Check [the guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/proper-to-2x/?view=aspnetcore-7.0) for such migration